# How to add a pop up aspx page to your web part?

Tags: javascript, web-part, popup

I'd like to have a pop up that contains an aspx page.  It appears that adding an aspx page to a web part is not possible.  When I went to add a new item to the project the closest I could find were ascx or htm.

In an effort to get *something* I tried adding the htm page, first to the project and then to the Layouts Mapped folder.  Everytime I opened the popup it gave me a 404 error.

Here is the html/javascript I had when the file was in the Layouts mapped folder:

```
<a href="javascript:OpenPopUpPage('ProjectName/test.htm');">Show Me the Pop-Up!</a>
```

and here is what I had when it was in the project base:

```
<a href="javascript:OpenPopUpPage('test.htm');">Show Me the Pop-Up!</a>
```

Does it look like I have done anything wrong here?  Is it possible to add an aspx to a web part?  If not, is there an alternative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your URL is also misconstructed. If your ASPX sits in the layouts folder you should add the path to that page including _layouts.

```
<a href="javascript:SP.UI.ModalDialog.OpenPopUpPage('/_layouts/mypage.aspx');">
```

Comment: +1, awesome.  That worked for the html page, no more 404 error!  Do you know if it's possible to add a aspx to my web part or should I just try with an ascx or something?  I definitely need the pop up to have ASP.NET functionality.

Comment: The popup expects a page like an ASPX or HTML file. ASCX files cannot be opened directly from the client due to it being a control and not a page. ASP.NET actively blocks requests for ASCX files coming from the client.

Comment: Also note that 'add a aspx to a webpart' is something that is not possible. A web part is an ASP.NET Control, a page is, well, a page. The two have little in common. You can add a page to your project and then have your webpart render a link to that page, for instance using that script.

Comment: Hmmm, all components and functionality need to be contained in a single WSP file.  Is there a way for me to do that if I need to have a WSP?

Comment: Actually I was able to add an "Application Page" which is an aspx page.  I'll keep you posted on how well that works for my needs

Comment: FYI, I was able to get the pop up working with the aspx page.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the js namespaces

Try replacing the call with `SP.UI.ModalDialog.OpenPopUpPage()`

```
<a href="javascript:SP.UI.ModalDialog.OpenPopUpPage('yoururl');">Show Me the Pop-Up!</a>
```

Comment: No that didn't work.  Just to be clear, I *am* getting the SharePoint style pop up.  It just has a 404 error inside the pop up.